# Mapping Over List In A Tree

Tags: haskell

I need your help in solving the following 2 functions/problems:

**1)**

I have to replace the elements in a tree. The Branch of the tree can have any number of sub branches as shown below in the code.

```
data Tree a = Leaf a | Branch a [(Tree a)] deriving (Show)

mapmtree :: (a -> a) -> Tree a -> Tree a
mapmtree f (Leaf a) = (f a)
mapmtree f (Branch a c) = Branch (map f a) (mapmtree f c)
```

I have to move through the elements and change them. My problem is in the last line. The mapmtree function accepts (Tree a) but the branch can have a list of sub branches so it is not possible to compile the above code since it gives error. How can i call the mapmtree function on the sub lists of the branch?

This is the error i get when i load it:

```
Couldn't match expected type `Tree a'
           against inferred type `[Tree a]'
    In the second argument of `mapmtree', namely `c'
    In the second argument of `Branch', namely `(mapmtree f c)'
    In the expression: Branch (map f a) (mapmtree f c)
```

**2)**

The second one deals with turning a tree into list in **depth-first**  This is the code i have now but am stucked and don't know how to go further:

```
data Tree a = Leaf a | Branch a [(Tree a)] deriving (Show)

mtree2list :: Tree a -> [a]
mtree2list (Leaf a) = [a]
mtree2list (Branch a c) = a : (mtree2list c)
```

Need help also how to implement it. The same problem as the above, the Branch can have many sub trees and need to go through them in **depth-first** to make a list of the elements.

Please am a total beginner in Haskell so don't be angry at me.

Thanks

Comment: Please notice, that you actually want to create a Functor. SO change `maptree` to `fmap` and make it instance of the `Functor` typeclass. You have to change your typesignatue indeed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1)**

First off all I notice that you're doing `map f a` although `a` is a single value, not a list¹. So you should be doing `f a` not `map f a`.

Now to the problem you actually asked about:

You're right that it doesn't work because `c` is a list of trees and `mapmtree` only wants a single tree. So what do you do? You apply `mapmtree` to each tree in the list of trees and then use the list of resulting trees as the list of trees for the new Branch. How do you do that? Using `map` on the list:

```
mapmtree f (Branch a c) = Branch (f a) (map (mapmtree f) c)
```

**2)**

As in 1) you use `map` to apply `mtree2list` to each tree in `c`. The result will be a list of lists². To turn this list of lists into a flat list, you can use the `concat` function, which does exactly that.

---

¹ Unless you're calling `mapmtree` on a tree of lists, of course.

² Because each tree is mapped to a list by `mtree2list` and `map` then returns a list containing the results of calling `mtree2list`.

Comment: Thank you soo much for your reply. It has help me increase my knowledge in haskell a little bit. The code are working now.

Answer (score 2):

Additionally, the first part is wrong since your function (a -> a) isn't giving you the Tree a type you want. You need to change that to

```
mapmtree f (Leaf a) = Leaf (f a)
```